# Eclipse Toolbar Icons appearing in Linux when RCP product is created

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I am exporting my rcp product to both Windows and Linux OS. When I do so, I can view some toolbar icons of Eclipse in Linux OS. In windows OS it is working fine without any Eclipse related icons. How to remove toolbar icons of Eclipse IDE in Linux?

Comment: You need to give us a lot more information than this. Is the an e4 or traditional 3.x RCP? Are you using your own `ActionBarAdvisor`? If not how are you hiding the standard toolbar icons.

Comment: It is an e4 RCP application. I am using my own ActionBarAdvisor and hiding all the WorkbenchWindow Actions in my ActionBarAdvisor class.

Comment: If you are using `ActionBarAdvisor` it is **not** an e4 application - it is a 3.x compatibility mode app. Show us your `ActionBarAdvisor`.